# How to pass error param in SWIFT with saveInBackgroundWithTarget

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have to use

```
currentEmployer.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(self, selector: "reloadData")
```

to reload a TableView. This call works, but as described in the docs, you can pass an error parameter to the function listed in the selector to check whether something failed. How can I pass the error parameter to my reloadData function?

Kind regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `saveInBackgroundWithTarget:selector:` is deprecated, since it's no longer in [the `PFObject` documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html).  Try `saveInBackgroundWithBlock:` instead:

```
currentEmployer.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { succeeded, error in
    if succeeded {
        self.reloadData()
    } else {
        // Handle error. Maybe something like this:
        self.showAlertWithError(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: the reason why I choose saveInBackgroundWithTarget over saveInBackgroundWithBlock is the fact, that I had to call self.tableView.reloadData() from inside the block of the origin saveInBackgroundWithBlock function but Xcode always claims that ViewController has no member named "tableView". It's defined as a strong Outlet property and I can call "self.tableView.reloadData()" on the first level of a block - but I have multiple blocks in a hierarchy and on the second level of a saveInBackgroundBlock "self.tableView.reloadData()" is claimed to be no member of the ViewController...

Comment: okay, I could fix it using the not deprecated method "saveInBackgroundWithBlock" by defining my own "reloadData()" method and call it in the block